# On which Stack Exchange site should I post a question about releasing a PC App? (not a programming question)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm writing a Windows/Mac app, it is the same as a mobile app I have. I have no experience releasing PC apps, only mobile apps. On mobile I know how to monetize with ads and sales, but on PC I have no idea what the preferred methods are.

So, which Stack Exchange site would be the right one to ask that type of question?

Answer (score -1):

**If your app is Free Software/Open Source** you can try [OpenSource.SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). From their help page:

> As a general rule, we use the FSF's four freedoms and the OSI's open source definition as a guide to what is considered to be in the scope of "free and open".
>
> You've come to the right place if you have questions about:
>
> - the history and philosophies of the FSF, OSI, CC etc
> - understanding, applying, and complying with Free & Open licenses
> - how communities collaborate together to produce, distribute, market and sometimes **monetize these projects**
> - what license to use for a specific situation - but please read "How do I ask for a license recommendation?" first

There are [42 questions tagged monetization](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monetization), a search for [monetize returns 64 results](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/search?q=monetize), and using our main site a [search for "monetize personal computer program"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=monetize+personal+computer+program) directs you **only** to [SoftwareEngineering.SE's FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c/8067#8067); which directs people to that site.

Another search on our main search engine for ["sell personal computer program"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=sell+personal+computer+program&page=1) turns up 92 non-helpful results. A search for ["sell computer program"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=sell+computer+program&page=1) turns up 879 results, which also don't appear to be helpful.

Be certain to read all the relevant pages on OpenSource.SE's help regarding asking questions, and check their meta and site for questions similar to your own.